# Finding indices given condition in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a numpy matrix, such as:

```
[[1,2,3],
[0,59,2],
[54,4,2]]
```

Now I want to find the indices, where all values are greater than 50 (not the maximum).
This should give me `[1,1],[2,0]`.

Other than iterating through, checking each value and keeping track of indices for values which obey condition and then returning these pairs - how do you do this efficiently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use either numpy.where or numpy.argwhere:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[99, 2, 3],
              [0, 59, 2],
              [54, 4, 2]])
np.where(A > 50)
# (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 0]))
np.argwhere(A > 50)
# array([[0, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [2, 0]])
```

Comment: thank you! By any chance do you know the algorithmic complexity of this in comparison to for loop or list comprehension?

Comment: @redrubia The algorithmic complexity is the same, it's linear in the number of elements in `A`. There is no way of finding all elements greater then 50 except by comparing every element to 50 (unless you happen to know that `A` is sorted or something like that). But it's still much faster for large arrays because numpy uses compiled code which doesn't have all the overhead of dynamic python code (dynamic type checking and all that stuff).

Answer (score -1):

How about list comprehension?

```
ind = [[i,j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3) if A[i][j]>50]
```